# how to fire trigger in mssql server automatically(i.e daily)

Tags: sql-server

this is my trigger in sql server. I want this trigger to fire automatically( i.e daily) instead of update...

```
create trigger  trig_name
on tab_name
for update
as 
begin
declare   @id int,@innn int
declare @dif int
declare   @inn int
set @id=(select whateverid from inserted)
set @inn = (select DATEDIFF(DAY,INSERTDT,UPDATEDDT) from tab_name where whateverid=@id)
set @innn =(select DATEDIFF(DAY,INSERTDT,GETDATE()) from tab_name where whateverid=@id)
set @dif = @inn-@innn
 update tab_name set due=@dif from tab_name where whateverid= @id
end
```

Comment: You mean you want to update daily? Why not use schedule? SQL Server agent can create job that you can set to run daily and you can track it easily.

Comment: urm given you use `inserted`, it wouldn't work as is.  But in general you need to create a stored procedure then you can use SQL agent to schedule it to run whenever.

Comment: Your trigger is broken anyway - `inserted` can contain 0, 1, or *many* rows. So `set @id=(select whateverid from inserted)` is going to randomly select a `whateverid` value for *one* of those rows (or `NULL` if `inserted` is empty) and then ignore any other rows.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new SQL Agent Job, and add a Transact SQL step:

```
update tab_name 
set due = DATEDIFF(DAY, INSERTDT, UPDATEDDT) - DATEDIFF(DAY, INSERTDT, GETDATE())
```

Obviously, unlike the trigger, you can't update those that have just been updated.  So this will update all 'due' fields based on the time it runs.

I would consider create a stored proc and getting the job to run that instead.  It easier manager, and less likely to get missed in the future.

Comment: I might recommend a computed column using that expression, rather than storing the value at all. After all, a computed column never falls "out of date" and needs **no** maintenance.

Comment: Agreed, that's a much better solution.